# How to find rows in SQL / MySQL with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, row, sql-order-by

I have a table *user*

```
Name     | Poin 
================== 
user1    | 20 
user2    | 30 
user3    | 80 
user4    | 60 
user5    | 10 
user6    | 85
```

And I have SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
ORDER BY poin
```

It would appear that the data sequence based on points.

But what I need is data like this (for example, I was user1):

```
Position 1 : user6 - 85 point 
Position 2 : user3 - 80 point 
Position 3 : user4 - 60 point
```

You are `position 5 : user1 - 20 point`

## UPDATE

I use this sql

> SELECT x.name, 
>          x.position  
>  
>   FROM (SELECT t.user, 
>               @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position 
>               FROM user  t 
>              JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
>              ORDER BY t.poin DESC) x
>   WHERE x.user = 'user1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give current rank for `user1`:

```
SELECT count(*) AS rank
FROM user
WHERE poin >= (SELECT poin FROM user WHERE name = 'user1')
```

Small issue with this query is that if another user has the same points, it will be assigned the same rank - whether it is correct, it is questionable.

If you want to simply add rank for every user, use this:

```
SELECT
    @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,
    name,
    poin
FROM user,
    (SELECT @rank:=0) r
ORDER BY poin DESC
```

You can use small variation of this query to get rank of single user, but avoid issue of the same ranking ambiguity:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,
        name,
        poin
    FROM user,
        (SELECT @rank:=0) r
    ORDER BY poin DESC
) x
WHERE name = 'user1'
```

Comment: thx for response @mvp..
I use the first choice of you. 
but there was a slight problem when there is a point value equal to User1.
how do i fix this ..
thx before.. :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to give an option to disable "ties" - all users will have unique rankings, even if they have the same score

Comment: GREAT.. this work. why did not I think to do multiple queries like that :p .... ok thank you so much @mvp .. Your partner helps .. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`select * from user order by poin desc`

Hope this helps

Comment: @johannes: is that so? Your code showed you knew about queries and all. So dint made an explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY poin DESC
```

The `ORDER` BY keyword is used to sort the result-set by a specified column.

The `ORDER BY` keyword sorts the records in ascending order by default.

If you want to sort the records in a descending order, you can use the `DESC` keyword.

#### SQL ORDER BY Syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name(s) ASC|DESC
```

Comment: fauzi wants the position and not description of 'order by'. I really dont understand how this answer helps user.

Comment: I understand the question is the he wants to order the users, I think he used position just for example

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP needs user current position (rank). Your query simply does not have it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Name, 
        Poin, 
        @rowNum := @rowNum + 1 AS position
FROM    user
JOIN    (SELECT @rowNum := 0) r
ORDER BY poin;
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, but I can not use it because it has to process all data to rank

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
SELECT count(*) AS rank 
FROM user 
WHERE poin >= (SELECT poin FROM user  WHERE name = 'user1')
```

Has a problem when is has double point in different rows.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  Name, 
        Poin, 
        @rowNum := @rowNum + 1 AS position
FROM    user
JOIN    (SELECT @rowNum := 0) r
ORDER BY poin DESC;
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, but I can not use it because it has to process all data to rank

Comment: @a.fauzi: Glad to hear that. If this is the answer that helped you and brought you wonders then just click on the "right/tick" in the upper left side down to "-1" scroll-bar so that other users will find it in short span of time if they'd look for exactly or relevant answer.